# Trying to do `askForSignIn` fails for linked account

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying to implement account linking against our OAuth service.

I tried logging in using `gala-demo.appspot.com` and that seems to work.

Calling `askForSignIn()` seem to fail when invoked, i don't get any calls back to my web service so the error seems to be upstream.

The response i see in the debug info when using the assistant simulator is:

`expected_inputs[0].possible_intents[0]: intent 'actions.intent.SIGN_IN' is only supported for version 2 and above.`

Any ideas?

On another note; If i set `signInRequired` on the action configuration for the welcome intent, it seems to get further but gives a bad sign in redirect link in simulator and on a device it opens a dialog that just disappears (looks like a successful login) but no response back to the web service.

Comment: how to do same thing when using dialogflow instead of sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you're probably using the old v1 API. I suggest you to check the migration guide:
https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/v1/migration

Cheers!

Comment: Great! This solved the intent problem! it did not solve the errors linking the account, but that's a different issue.

Comment: I think one reason it failed was that i did not restart the simulator after doing the `gactions update` making the changes to not take effect, might be worth noting for anyone else having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Sign in intent doesn't work at the moment as clearly explained in the docs, it's just something you can use for test in the emulator, but it's not available in production